# how can I launch my blockchain through bitcoin-core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

How can you run your blockchain, not through regtest, but a real one

Answer (score 1):

It provides no such feature.

Bitcoin Core is designed to interact with the Bitcoin blockchain and network, including some of its test chains/network (regtest, testnet, signet).

Comment: and how was the bitcoin network launched then?

Comment: Please don't try. Instead look for reasons and resources to contribute to bitcoin. It is easy to do what you are trying to achieve. Its easier to contribute to bitcoin.

Comment: @SlimThugs The Bitcoin network was launched by defining its rules in code and by people running that code. If you wanted to launch a different network, you would have to change the code, otherwise you'd just be joining the existing network.

Comment: and if you launch your bitcoin network , will it be possible to connect via bitcoin core by changing the sources ?

Comment: You can modify the source code, and distribute the source code, and if you do that right, all others that use the program may end up participating in a network that defines an alternative currency. But it won't be Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to fork the code, with the only limitations described in [COPYING](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/COPYING).

After you do so, if that creates an alternative chain, then any troubles you have onwards are off topic in this site.